# Optimize or reuse subquery in sqlite to filter results

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sqlite database that represents game activities and results for individual characters.

Here is the overview:

[image]

An activity can have one or more modes (represented in the modes table).

[image]

First, here is the entire query:

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    activity.mode as activity_mode,
    character_activity_stats.id as character_activity_stats_index  
FROM
    character_activity_stats
INNER JOIN
    activity ON character_activity_stats.activity = activity.id,
    character on character_activity_stats.character = character.id,
    member on member.id = character.member
WHERE
    5 in (select mode from modes where activity = activity.id) AND
    32 not in (select mode from modes where activity = activity.id) AND
    character_activity_stats.character = 1
ORDER BY
    activity.period DESC
```

I need to query to get all activities which have a specific mode, but does not contain another specific mode.

i.e. I have an activity, and it has modes of 3, 5, 27. I want to include it if it includes mode 5, and does not include mode 32.

I do that with this in the where clause:

```sql
5 in (select mode from modes where activity = activity.id) AND
32 not in (select mode from modes where activity = activity.id) AND
```

This seems to be working, but is very slow when going through 7000 activities. I have to run the (select mode from modes where activity = activity.id) query twice. Is there a way to run the subquery once and reuse it? or is there a generally better way to approach this?

Here is the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN

```
6   0   0   SEARCH TABLE character USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
13  0   0   SEARCH TABLE member USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
16  0   0   SCAN TABLE character_activity_stats
20  0   0   SEARCH TABLE activity USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
26  0   0   CORRELATED LIST SUBQUERY 1
28  26  0   SCAN TABLE modes
41  0   0   CORRELATED LIST SUBQUERY 2
43  41  0   SCAN TABLE modes
106 0   0   USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

Answer (score 0):

Use co-related sub-query using `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` which will be way faster than your IN query as follows:

```
SELECT
    *,
    activity.mode as activity_mode,
    character_activity_stats.id as character_activity_stats_index  
FROM
    character_activity_stats
INNER JOIN
    activity ON character_activity_stats.activity = activity.id,
    character on character_activity_stats.character = character.id,
    member on member.id = character.member
WHERE
    exist (select 1 from modes where activity = activity.id and mode = 5) AND
    not exists (select 1 from modes where activity = activity.id and mode = 32) AND
    character_activity_stats.character = 1
ORDER BY
    activity.period DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM activity a INNER JOIN modes m
ON m.activity = a.id
WHERE m.mode IN (5, 32)
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING MAX(m.mode) = 5
```

returns only the rows from `activity` that meet your conditions.

You can join the above query instead of `activity` in your query and remove the conditions from the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *, a.mode activity_mode, cas.id character_activity_stats_index  
FROM character_activity_stats cas
INNER JOIN ( 
  SELECT a.*
  FROM activity a INNER JOIN modes m
  ON m.activity = a.id
  WHERE m.mode IN (5, 32)
  GROUP BY a.id
  HAVING MAX(m.mode) = 5
) a ON cas.activity = a.id
INNER JOIN character on cas.character = c.id
INNER JOIN member on m.id = c.member
WHERE cas.character = 1
ORDER BY a.period DESC
```